# A small Python text adventure "frame"

Tags: python, game, python-2.x

I've been working on a small "frame" for a text adventure in Python.

So it's less of a real adventure and more of a small testing location for all the commands.

I pretty much just started learning Python after completing the Codecademy tutorial and don't want to pick up any bad habits.

```
#Text Adventure

import shlex



def map():
    print ' _____________________________ '
    print '|         |         |         |'
    print '|         |         |         |'
    print '| Room B  = Room D  =  Room E |'
    print '|   Jack  |  Sword  |   Bear  |'
    print '|         |         |         |'
    print '|____||___|____||___|____\____|'
    print '|         |         |         |'
    print '|         |         |         |'
    print '|  Steve  |  Jesse  |  Room F |'
    print '| Room A  = Room C  =  Chest  |'
    print '|         |         |         |'
    print '|_________|_________|_________|'



#The Room class
class Room(object):
    def __init__(self, location,objectsinRoom, containersinRooom, wallsinRoom,peopleinRoom,hasDoor,\
    description,descriptionpeople,descriptiondirections):

        self.location = location
        self.objectsinRoom = objectsinRoom
        self.containersinRooom = containersinRooom
        self.wallsinRoom = wallsinRoom
        self.peopleinRoom = peopleinRoom
        self.hasDoor = hasDoor
        self.description = description
        self.descriptionpeople = descriptionpeople
        self.descriptiondirections = descriptiondirections


#Returns what will be printed about the Room you're in right meow
    def display_Room(self):
        stri = (' ')

        itemprint = []
        contprint = []
        peopprint = []

        for item in self.objectsinRoom:
            if item.islocked == True:
                pass
            else:
                if item.incontainer == True:
                    itemprint.append('A ' + item.name + ' is in the ' + item.containername + '. ')
                else:
                    itemprint.append('A ' + item.name + ' is here.')
        stritem = stri.join(itemprint)

        for cont in self.containersinRooom:
            contprint.append(cont.text)
        strcont = stri.join(contprint)

        for people in self.peopleinRoom:
            if people.state == 'alive':
                peopprint.append(' ' +  people.name + ' is here. ')
            elif people.state != 'alive':
                peopprint.append(' ' +  people.name + "'s dead body is here. ")
        strpeop = stri.join(peopprint)

        return self.description + strpeop + strcont + stritem

#The class for NPCs
class People(object):
    def __init__(self,location,name,text,description,state):
        self.location = location
        self.name = name
        self.text = text
        self.description = description
        self.state = state

#Pretty much useless
    def printText(self):
        print self.text


#Moves the player to another room
    def go(self,location,Decision):

        newlocation = list(self.location)


        if Decision == 'go north' or Decision == 'go n' or Decision == 'n':
            newlocation[1] += 1
            test = world.get(tuple(newlocation))
            if test == None:
                print 'You cannot go there'
            else:
                if test.wallsinRoom[2] == False and (test.hasDoor == None or test.hasDoor.islocked == False\
                or test.hasDoor.dir1 != 'n'):
                    Ply.location = tuple(newlocation)
                elif test.wallsinRoom[2] == True:
                    print 'There is a wall here. '
                elif test.hasDoor.islocked == True:
                    print 'There is a door in the way. '

        elif Decision == 'go south' or Decision == 'go s' or Decision == 's':
            newlocation[1] -= 1
            test = world.get(tuple(newlocation))
            if test == None:
                print 'You cannot go there'
            else:
                if test.wallsinRoom[0] == False and (test.hasDoor == None or test.hasDoor.islocked == False\
                or test.hasDoor.dir1 != 's'):

                    Ply.location = tuple(newlocation)
                elif test.wallsinRoom[0] == True:
                    print 'There is a wall here. '
                elif test.hasDoor.islocked == True:
                    print 'There is a door in the way. '


        elif Decision == 'go east' or Decision == 'go e' or Decision == 'e':
            newlocation[0] += 1
            test = world.get(tuple(newlocation))
            if test == None:
                print 'You cannot go there'
            else:
                if test.wallsinRoom[3] == False and (test.hasDoor == None or test.hasDoor.islocked == False\
                or test.hasDoor.dir1 != 'e'):
                    Ply.location = tuple(newlocation)
                elif test.wallsinRoom[3] == True:
                    print 'There is a wall here. '
                elif test.hasDoor.islocked == True:
                    print 'There is a door in the way. '


        elif Decision == 'go west' or Decision == 'go w' or Decision == 'w':
            newlocation[0] -= 1
            test = world.get(tuple(newlocation))
            if test == None:
                print 'You cannot go there'
            else:
                if test.wallsinRoom[1] == False and (test.hasDoor == None or test.hasDoor.islocked == False\
                or test.hasDoor.dir1 != 'w'):
                    Ply.location = tuple(newlocation)
                elif test.wallsinRoom[1] == True:
                    print 'There is a wall here. '
                elif test.hasDoor.islocked == True:
                    print 'There is a door in the way. '



#The Player class!
class Player(People):
    def __init__(self,location,name,text,state):
        self.location = location
        self.name = name
        self.text = text
        self.state = state


#Actually prints the description of your location
    def printlocation(self,location):
        return world.get(self.location).display_Room()

#Adds to inventory n shit
    def take(self,location,Decision):
        tokens = shlex.split(Decision)
        if len(tokens) != 2  or tokens[1] not in objects:
            print "This doesn't exist."
        else:
            if Ply.location == objects[tokens[1]].location:
                if objects[tokens[1]].ininv == 'no':
                    if objects[tokens[1]].islocked == False:
                        Inventory.append(objects[tokens[1]].name)
                        print 'Taken'
                        objects[tokens[1]].ininv = 'yes'
                        objects[tokens[1]].incontainer = 'yes'
                        objects[tokens[1]].containername = None
                        world.get(self.location).objectsinRoom.remove(objects[tokens[1]])
                    else:
                        print "You don't see that"
                elif objects[tokens[1]].ininv == 'no':
                    print "You already have that"

            else:
                print "You don't see that"

#Removes from inventory n shit
    def drop(self,location,Decision):
        tokens = shlex.split(Decision)
        if len(tokens) != 2 or tokens[1] not in Inventory:
            print "You don't have that"
        else:
            objects[tokens[1]].ininv = 'no'
            Inventory.remove(objects[tokens[1]].name)
            objects[tokens[1]].location = self.location
            world.get(self.location).objectsinRoom.append(objects[tokens[1]])
            print 'Dropped'

#Puts something in a container.
    def put(self,location,Decision):
        tokens = shlex.split(Decision)
        if len(tokens) != (4) or tokens[1] not in Inventory:
            print "You don't have that"
        elif tokens[2] != 'in' and tokens[2] != 'on':
            print 'What?'
        elif tokens[2] == 'in':
            if tokens[3] not in containers:
                print "The thing you want that in doesn't exist"
            else:
                objects[tokens[1]].ininv = 'no'
                Inventory.remove(objects[tokens[1]].name)
                objects[tokens[1]].location = self.location
                world.get(self.location).objectsinRoom.append(objects[tokens[1]])
                objects[tokens[1]].incontainer = True
                objects[tokens[1]].containername = tokens[3]
                print 'Put.'
        elif tokens[2] == 'on' and tokens[3] == 'floor':
            if tokens[1] not in Inventory:
                print "You don't have that"
            else:
                objects[tokens[1]].ininv = 'no'
                Inventory.remove(objects[tokens[1]].name)
                objects[tokens[1]].location = self.location
                world.get(self.location).objectsinRoom.append(objects[tokens[1]])
                print 'Dropped'

#Opens a door or container
    def open(self,location,Decision):
        tokens = shlex.split(Decision)
        if len(tokens) != 2 or tokens[1] not in containers:
            if tokens[1] == 'door':
                unlock(Decision)
            else:
                print "This doesn't exist."
        else:
            containers[tokens[1]].isopen = True
            print 'Opened'
            containers[tokens[1]].text = "An open " + containers[tokens[1]].name +" is here. "
            for item in itemsincontainers[containers[tokens[1]]]:
                item.islocked = False

#Closes a container
    def close(self,location,Decision):
        tokens = shlex.split(Decision)
        if len(tokens) != 2 or tokens[1] not in containers:
            print "This doesn't exist."
        else:
            containers[tokens[1]].isopen = False
            print 'Closed'
            containers[tokens[1]].text = "A " + containers[tokens[1]].name +" is here. "
            for item in itemsincontainers[containers[tokens[1]]]:
                item.islocked = True


#Talks to a NPC
    def talk(self,location,Decision):
        if Decision == 'talk steve' or Decision == 'talk to steve' or Decision == 'talk with steve':
            if self.location == Steve.location:
                if Jack.state == 'dead':
                    if gold.ininv == 'no':
                        print 'You killed Jack! Take this is a reward.'
                        print 'Gold added to Inventory'
                        Inventory.append(gold.name)
                    elif gold.ininv == 'yes':
                        print 'Thanks again, man.'
                elif Steve.state == 'dead':
                    print 'This person is dead.'\

                else:
                    Steve.printText()
            else:
                print "This person is not here."

        elif Decision == 'talk jack' or Decision == 'talk to jack' or Decision == 'talk with jack':
            if self.location == Jack.location:
                if Jack.state == 'dead':
                    print 'This person is dead.'
                else:
                    Jack.printText()
            else:
                print 'This person is not here'

        elif Decision == 'talk jesse' or Decision == 'talk to jesse' or Decision == 'talk with jesse':
            if self.location == Jesse.location:
                if Jesse.state == 'dead':
                    print 'this person is dead'
                elif 'gold' in Inventory:
                    Drug = raw_input('You wanna buy some drugs?')
                    if Drug == 'no':
                        print 'THEN FUCK OFF'
                    elif Drug == 'yes':
                        Inventory.remove('gold')
                        Inventory.append(meth.name)
                        print 'Gold removed from Inventory'
                        print 'Meth added to Inventory'
                else:
                    Jesse.printText()
            else:
                print 'This person is not here'


        elif Decision == 'talk bear' or Decision == 'talk to bear' or Decision == 'talk with bear':
            if self.location == Bear.location:
                if Bear.state == 'dead':
                    print 'this monster is dead'
                else:
                    Bear.printText()
                    print 'The bear killed you'
                    print 'Game over'
                    Ply.state = 'dead'
            else:
                print 'This thing is not here'

#Kills a NPC
    def kill(self,location,Decision):
        tokens = shlex.split(Decision)
        if len(tokens) == 2:
            if tokens[1] in people:
                if self.location == people[tokens[1]].location:
                    killhelp(tokens[1])
                else:
                    print 'This person is not here.'
            else:
                print 'This person does not exist'
        elif len(tokens) == 4:
            if tokens[2] == 'with':
                if tokens[1] in people:
                    if self.location == people[tokens[1]].location:
                        killhelpwithitem(tokens[3],tokens[1])
                    else:
                        print 'This person is not here.'
                else:
                    print 'This person does not exist'
            else:
                print "This won't work"
        else:
            print "This doesn't work"

#The item class
class Item(object):
    def __init__(self,name,text,location,cankill,ininv,incontainer,islocked,containername):
        self.name = name
        self.text = text
        self.location = location
        self.cankill = cankill
        self.ininv = ininv
        self.incontainer = incontainer
        self.islocked = islocked
        self.containername = containername

#Container Class
class Container(object):
    def __init__(self,name,text,location,isopen,contains):
        self.name = name
        self.text = text
        self.location = location
        self.isopen = isopen
        self.contains = contains

#Door class
class Door(object):
    def __init__(self,name,text,location1,location2,dir1,dir2,islocked,needskey,key):
        self.name = name
        self.text = text
        self.location1 = location1
        self.location2 = location2
        self.dir1 = dir1
        self.dir2 = dir2
        self.islocked = islocked
        self.needskey = needskey
        self.key = key


#helps the killmethod find out, if kill works
def killhelp(victim):
    Dec = raw_input('With what?')
    Dec2 = Dec.lower()
    if Dec2 in objects:
        if Dec2 in Inventory:
            if objects[Dec2].cankill == 'yes':
                killcons(victim)
            else:
                print "You can't kill with that!"
        else:
            print "You don't have that."
    else:
        print "This doesn't exist."

#helps the killmethod find out, if kill works
def killhelpwithitem(Item,victim):
    if Item in objects:
        if Item in Inventory:
            if objects[Item].cankill == 'yes':
                killcons(victim)
            else:
                print "You can't kill with that!"
        else:
            print "You don't have that."
    else:
        print "This doesn't exist."

#The consequences of a kill
def killcons(victim):
    genericvictims = ['steve','jack','jesse']

    if victim in genericvictims:
        people[victim].state = 'dead'
        print victim + ' died. '
    else:
        if victim == 'myself':
            print 'You killed yourself. Good job, Really. Congratulations.'
            print 'Game over'
            Ply.state = 'dead'
        elif victim == 'bear':
            print 'YOU CANNOT KILL A BEAR GODDAMNIT'

#Prints your inventory
def inv():
    stri = ', '
    print 'You have ' + stri.join(Inventory)

#also opens stuff
#why is this not in the player class?
def unlock(Decision):
    tokens = shlex.split(Decision)
    otherlocation = list(Ply.location)
    if len(tokens) != 2 or tokens[1] != 'door' or Ply.location not in Doorslocations:
        if tokens[1] in containers:
            Ply.open(Ply.location,Decision)
        else:
            "This not exist, brother. "
    else:
        if Doorsdirection[Ply.location] == 'n':
            otherlocation[1] += 1
            Doorslocations.get(Ply.location).islocked = False
            print 'unlocked'

        elif Doorsdirection[Ply.location] == 'e':
            otherlocation[0] += 1
            Doorslocations.get(Ply.location).islocked = False
            print 'unlocked'

        elif Doorsdirection[Ply.location] == 's':
            otherlocation[1] -= 1
            Doorslocations.get(Ply.location).islocked = False
            print 'unlocked'

        elif Doorsdirection[Ply.location] == 'w':
            otherlocation[0] -= 1
            Doorslocations.get(Ply.location).islocked = False
            print 'unlocked'


#Examines an item.
def exam(Decision):
    tokens = shlex.split(Decision)
    if len(tokens) != 2 or tokens[0] != 'exam' or tokens[1] not in objects:
        print "This doesn't exist"
    else:
        if Ply.location == objects[tokens[1]].location or tokens[1] in Inventory:
            print objects[tokens[1]].text
        else:
            print "You don't see this"

#This doesn't work for some reason
def dodrugs():
    if 'meth' in Inventory:
        print 'YOU ARE HIGH'
        Inventory.remove('meth')
        meth.ininv = 'no'
    else:
        print "You don't have that"

#This is supposed to check at the end of turn, if something is supposed to happen
def script():
    pass

#prints the help thingy
def helpp():
    print "You can use the following commands:"
    print "go (north,south,west,east)"
    print "talk (person)"
    print "kill (person) with (item)"
    print "take (item)"
    print "drop (item)"
    print "open (door or container)"
    print "inventory"
    print "examine (item)"
    print "quit"


Inventory = []


sword = Item('sword','This is a sword',(2,2,1),'yes','no',False,False,None)
pistol = Item('pistol','This is a pistol',(3,1,1),'yes','no',True,True,'chest')
gold = Item('gold','This is gold',(1,1,1),'no','no',False,False,None)
meth = Item('meth','THIS IS SOME REALLY NICE BLUE METH',(1,2,1),'no','no',False,False,None)

objects = {
'sword': sword,
'gold': gold,
'meth': meth,
'pistol': pistol
}

objectsinroomA = []
objectsinroomB = []
objectsinroomC = [sword]
objectsinroomD = []
objectsinroomE = []
objectsinroomF = [pistol]



chest = Container('Chest','A chest is here. ',(3,1,1),False,None)

containers = {
'chest': chest

}

itemsinchest = [pistol]

itemsincontainers = {
chest: itemsinchest

}

containersinRoomA = []
containersinRoomB = []
containersinRoomC = []
containersinRoomD = []
containersinRoomE = []
containersinRoomF = [chest]



Door1 = Door('Door','This is a door. ',(3,1,1),(3,2,1),'n','s',True,False,None)

Doorslocations = {
(3,1,1): Door1,
(3,2,1): Door1

}


Doorsdirection = {
(3,1,1): Door1.dir1,
(3,2,1): Door1.dir2

}



Ply = Player((1,1,1),'Player','','alive')
Steve = People((1,1,1),'Steve',"Hi, I'm Steve. Dude, can you do me favor? Kill Jack.",'This is Steve','alive')
Jack = People((1,2,1),'Jack',"Don't kill me! ",'This is Jack','alive')
Jesse = People((2,1,1),'Jesse','Piss off, bitch.','This is Jesse','alive')
Bear = People((3,2,1),'Bearbro','RAWWWRRR','THIS IS A FUCKING BEAR','alive')


people = {
'steve': Steve,
'jack': Jack,
'jesse': Jesse,
'bear' : Bear,
'myself': Ply,
}


peopleinRoomA = [Steve]
peopleinRoomB = [Jack]
peopleinRoomC = []
peopleinRoomD = [Jesse]
peopleinRoomE = [Bear]
peopleinRoomF = []




#               North,East,South,West,   Northlo,Eastlo,Southlo,Westlo
wallsinRoomA = [False,False,False,False, False,False,False,False]
wallsinRoomB = [False,False,False,False, False,False,False,False]
wallsinRoomC = [False,False,False,False, False,False,False,False]
wallsinRoomD = [False,False,False,False, False,False,False,False]
wallsinRoomE = [False,False,False,False,  False,False,Door1.islocked,False]
wallsinRoomF = [False,False,False,False,  Door1.islocked,False,False,False]


RoomA = Room((1,1,1),objectsinroomA,containersinRoomA,wallsinRoomA,peopleinRoomA,None,\
'You are in Room A.','',' You see a hallway to the north and to the east.')
RoomB = Room((1,2,1),objectsinroomB,containersinRoomB,wallsinRoomB,peopleinRoomB,None,\
'You are in Room B.','',' You see a hallway to the south and to the east.')
RoomC = Room((2,2,1),objectsinroomC,containersinRoomC,wallsinRoomC,peopleinRoomC,None,\
'You are in Room C.','',' You see a hallway to the west, to the east and to the south.')
RoomD = Room((2,1,1),objectsinroomD,containersinRoomD,wallsinRoomD,peopleinRoomD,None,\
'You are in Room D.','',' You see a hallway to the north and to the west.')
RoomE = Room((3,2,1),objectsinroomE,containersinRoomE,wallsinRoomE,peopleinRoomE,Door1,\
'You are in Room E. A door leading north is here. ',' ',' You see a hallway to the west and south.')
RoomF = Room((3,1,1),objectsinroomF,containersinRoomF,wallsinRoomF,peopleinRoomF,Door1,\
'You are in Room F. A door leading south is here.','',' You see a hallway to the west and north.')

world = {
(1,1,1):RoomA,
(1,2,1):RoomB,
(2,2,1):RoomC,
(2,1,1):RoomD,
(3,2,1):RoomE,
(3,1,1):RoomF
}






emptyline = '\n'

#The turn
def main():
    print "Welcome to my Text Adventure!"
    print "Use the 'help' command for help!"
    while Ply.state == 'alive':
        print Ply.printlocation(Ply.location)
        Decisionst = raw_input('>')
        Decisionstr = Decisionst.lower()
        lst = shlex.split(Decisionstr)
        if lst[0] == 'go' or lst[0] in 'nwse':
            Ply.go(Ply.location,Decisionstr)
        elif lst[0] == 'take' or lst[0] == 'get':
            Ply.take(Ply.location, Decisionstr)
        elif lst[0] == 'drop':
            Ply.drop(Ply.location,Decisionstr)
        elif lst[0] == 'quit':
            break
        elif lst[0] == 'talk':
            Ply.talk(Ply.location, Decisionstr)
        elif lst[0] == 'kill':
            Ply.kill(Ply.location,Decisionstr)
        elif lst[0] == 'die':
            killcons('myself')
        elif lst[0] == 'inventory' or lst[0] == 'inv' or lst[0] == 'i':
            inv()
        elif lst[0] == 'help':
            helpp()
        elif lst[0] == 'look':
            Ply.printlocation(Ply.location)
        elif lst[0] == 'open':
            Ply.open(Ply.location,Decisionstr)
        elif lst[0] == 'close':
            Ply.close(Ply.location,Decisionstr)
        elif lst[0] == 'put':
            Ply.put(Ply.location,Decisionstr)
        elif lst[0] == 'unlock':
            unlock(Decisionstr)
        elif lst[0] == 'examine' or 'exam':
            exam(Decisionstr)
        elif Decisionstr == 'do drugs' or 'do meth':
            dodrugs()
        script()

map()
main()
```

[Code from Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/R9rfd5kZ)

Answer (score 6):

There's a lot of code here, so it's hard to make a cohesive review. Instead I'll point out a few things related to your comment about avoiding picking up bad habits. The most common problems I see in your code are repeated work, and misplacement of responsibilities.

This isn't comprehensive. I'm not going to even touch on the question of whether the rooms and players should be code or external data files. But here goes:

#### `Room.__init__`

- I don't like having 9 parameters used by position. This makes things hard to read when invoking it; how do you know what's what in your `RoomA = Room(...)` lines? In your case, having named things like `wallsInRoomA` does clear this up, but that's not always the right answer.
- Good job wrapping the line. However note that inside matched braces, parentheses, or brackets, you don't need the trailing backslash.

#### `Room.display_Room`

- Calling it display_*Room* limits duck typing from the outside. Instead of being able to write one helper function which eventually delegates to a method called `display`, it has to know the type of the thing it's displaying, and call the appropriate method. Granted today that's only Rooms, and there is no helper.
- The comparisons like `if item.islocked == True` could be merely `if item.islocked`; the `== True` is redundant and distracting.
- The way an item is displayed seems to put the logic in `Room` instead of where I think it would belong: on `Item`. If the code that combines the item name and location was put on `Item` (and similarly for containers and people), this function would look more like this:

  ```
  def display():
      stri = ' '
      stritem = stri.join(item.display() for item in self.objectsinRoom if not item.islocked)
      strcont = stri.join(cont.display() for cont in self.containersinRooom)
      strpeop = stri.join(person.display() for person in self.peopleinRoom)
      return self.description + strpeop + strcont + stritem
  ```

#### `People.go`

- Should `go` be on `People` or `Player`? If you'll have wandering NPCs, it's fine on `People`, but if you won't, that seems somewhat odd to place this on the base class.
- The conversion of `self.location` from a tuple to a list and back is cute; it implicitly copies things, allows you to make your change, and so forth. But it also inherently limits how your world is laid out. You can't skip rooms. You can't make infinite loops. You can't make rooms by the North or South poles that don't follow the usual "square" terms. I would probably instead make the next room part of the doors.
- There's a lot of repeated code here. It would be good to refactor this, say by checking `Decision` and setting variables for the parts that differ (perhaps `index`, `move`, and `direction`), and then combining the remaining code. Or if you put this on a `Door`, you just have to look up your door, then process the door.
- Rather than using `world.get` and checking for None, I would probably just index `world[tuple(newlocation)]` and handle the potential `KeyError` in one spot. This change from get to indexing is more important in `Player.printlocation`, where using `world.get(self.location)` might return `None`, and you'd get a hard to read exception about `NoneType` not having attribute `display_Room`. If this was just `world[self.location].display_Room()`, you'd get a `KeyError` about `self.location` not being in the dictionary. Note as well that `printlocation` is not using the passed `location` parameter.

#### `Player.open` and `Player.close`

- There's a lot of reuse of `tokens[1]`. This should probably be given a name, at least in the else clauses, to make things more readable.

#### `Player.talk`

- The logic here should probably be refactored to the various NPCs. As is, all the talking logic of your entire set of NPCs is in the `Player` class. The trick is finding the balance between code like you have now, giving them each a different subclass, and trying to abstract just the bits you need somewhere inbetween.

Answer (score 3):

I'd second @michaelUrman's point about the room constructor- the long list of params makes it hard to follow what's going on. Since you don't do much with the constructor - you're not processing or otherwise mutating the incoming data - you could just create empty lists/dictionaries as needed and then have separate methods such as 'add_wall' and 'add_person' which would make the code read more legibly.

I'd be more aggressive about pushing the logic down into the different pieces. For example, you have a lot of logic in Room.display_Room() which depends on knowledge of what the state of different items in the room is. If the room simply called a standard "display" method that gave back the description of things in the room based on their own code the whole setup would be much cleaner. This is the much-discussed '[single-responsibility principle](http://www.oodesign.com/single-responsibility-principle.html)'

You could combine that with generalizing the various types of room contents into a common base class so you don't need to manage so many types of pieces in different variables.  This would make it easy to inventory and search through room contents and also make future expansion easier.  Here's a very simplified example.

```
class SimplifiedExampleRoom(object):
      def __init__(self, name, *walls, contents = [])
         self.Name = name
         self.Walls = (w for w in walls)
         self.Contents = contents

      def add_items (self, *items):
         self.Contents += list(items)

      def displayl(self):
         return "\n".join([item.display() for item in self.Contents])

 class RoomItem(object):

     def __init__(self, name, description, **options):
        self.Name = name

        self.Description = description
        self.Options = options # this is a dictionary so you can add optional 
                               # keyword arguments without changing constructors 
                               # in derived classes

    def display(self):
        return "you see a %s" % self.Description

  class ContainerItem(RoomItem):
       OPEN = 'open'
       CLOSED = 'closed' 

        def__init__(self, name, descripton, **opts):
           super(self, ContainerItem).__init__(name, description, **opts)
           self.Contents = []
           self.State = self.CLOSED

       def add_item(self, item):
           self.Contents.add

       def remove_item(self, item):
           if item in self.Contents:
              self.Contents.remove(item)

       def display(self):
          if self.State == self.CLOSED:
              return "you see a closed %s" % self.Description
          else:
              contents = "\n   *  ".join([item.Name for item in self.Contents])
              header = "you see an open %s. Inside you see:"  % self.Description
              return header  + contents

   class Person(RoomItem):

        def__init__(self, name, descripton, **opts):
           super(self, Person).__init__(name, description, **opts)
           self.Alive  = True

        def kill(self):
           self.Alive = False
           return "%s falls lifeless to the floor" % self.Name             

        def display(self):
           if self.Alive:
              return self.description
           else:
              return "You see the lifeless body of %s sprawled on the floor" % self.Name
```